# nothing is displayed when testing my app

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

originally when i tried to test my app i was getting this

> [2685:70b] Application windows are expected to have a root view
>   controller at the end of application launch

and so i changed ccAppDelegate.m

From this

```
    @implementation ccAppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    return YES;
}
```

To this

```
#import "ccAppDelegate.h"
#import "ccViewController.h"


@implementation ccAppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // ... Other code

    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    UIViewController *viewController = [[UIViewController alloc] init];

    self.window.rootViewController = viewController;
    self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

now it is no longer crashing but nothing appears but a white screen

what can i do to fix this?
i have a copy of my work here if anyone wishes to have a look at all the code
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3_fSZXQB18lVzZuQVdpT3dnWjQ/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: What you want to appear? You created empty controller with empty view - and you see it.

Comment: Like @Lanorkin said there's nothing to display ... it's an empty view controller.

Comment: there shouldn't be an empty view controller there should be at least an image view and a table how do i fix this?

Comment: You also gave the empty view controller a white background. If you change it to redColor you will get a red screen. You need to launch ccViewController instead of UIViewController. See @Sr.Richie for the correct answer below

Answer (score 3):

as stated in the comments, you're creating and displaying an empty view controller as the root view controller. As result, you're seeing your brand new empty view controller.

If you want to use your view controller as the root one, you should change the line

```
 UIViewController *viewController = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
```

to:

```
 MyCustomViewController *viewController = [[MyCustomViewController alloc] init];
```

where obviously `MyCustomViewController` should be replaced with the name of your class ( I think it is `ccViewController` but I'm not sure)

Comment: ok so i tried this and now its going back to [3047:70b] Application windows are expected to have a root view controller at the end of application launch

Comment: Have you changed ONLY the line I've indicated you?

Comment: yes i have and this project is starting to really stress me out

Comment: are you using storyboard?

Answer (score 0):

Your method is good but to see anything onscreen you need to add anything rg. `UIButton`, `UIImageView`. I assume that you are doing everything in code so if this is hard for you why don't you try [Storyboarding](http://www.raywenderlich.com/50308/storyboards-tutorial-in-ios-7-part-1).

Anyway, just paste this code and you'll see a red background:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // ... Other code

    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    UIViewController *viewController = [[UIViewController alloc] init];

    self.window.rootViewController = viewController;
    self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

All I've changed in your code is `[UIColor whiteColor]` to `[UIColor redColor]`.